# How to create PBR metal material from scratch in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture-mapping, pbr

I'm not familiar with Physically Based Shading/Rendering, so need some tips..

Trying to make simple metallic material for cannon pipe in Unity3D (see image#1 below, that mesh is just default unity cylinder primitive)
[image: Unity PBR cannon, not]
Below are some examples of what would be nice (painted metal, or just some dirty metal, no need to have those worn edges)

- http://plyczkowski.deviantart.com/art/PBR-Smart-Material-Painted-Metal-499427545
- http://static.wixstatic.com/media/a65e38_f250817ee6494a05a8e98f4be4cbc955.png_srz_p_1200_675_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_png_srz

I have seen many PBR reference color charts, but not getting similar results..
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/02/18/working-with-physically-based-shading-a-practical-approach/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
Just add Reflection probe and everything that should reflect will be reflect. (then just adjust smoothness or metallic map to have variation)

Relevant PBR texturing guides:
https://www.allegorithmic.com/pbr-guide
https://www.cleansourcecode.com/index.php/blog/pbr-texturing-and-the-standard-shader/

Results:
[image: shiny metal]